XMLPRC in google cloud
I am trying to use xmlprc.client in google cloud. Here is the code I want to execute :
import xmlrpc.client
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))

It is working locally on my machine, so it is not a problem of URL. When the code is exported to Google Cloud, I have this error:
Exception on / [POST]
OSError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol
Thank you for any help.

Please include a minimal repro of your solution so that others can try it. To which Google service are you deploying it and how? From what I understand of your code, it's not making any RPCs and so it shouldn't generate a POST error.

I am deploying it on Google Cloud functions.  And the full code is there. However here is some more traceback :
File "/workspace/communicator.py", line 11, in init
self.connect()
File "/workspace/communicator.py", line 15, in connect
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1429, in init
raise OSError("unsupported XML-RPC protocol")
OSError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol

I looked at xmlrpc/client.py and the "unsupported XML-RPC protocol" error is thrown if the URL scheme is not "http" or "https".

I wrote a simple XML-RPC server and client. I deployed the client to Cloud Functions (gen1) and was able to successfully invoke the Cloud Function function and the remote RPC.

Thank you very much for your help, indeed the url was loaded through a method that did not return the proper URL
